# Formatting SMS sent from android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, sms

I have a relatively easy problem but its causing me a headache. I want to send an sms from a phonegap app running in android.

I am using this code snippet

```
window.location.href = "sms:12345?body=message \nMessage line 2";
```

Now this works fine except for one thing. I cant create a new line in the message body. \n has no effect and doesnt even show. I need to have new lines in the message format but unable to do so.

My Regards,
Hassan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are passing the message as a URL parameter, you need to URL encode it.

```
window.location.href = "sms:12345?body=message+%0AMessage+line+2";
```

Here is a reference on [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot to include that you also need to URL encode the spaces. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I used "%0D%0A" for new line in sms body